# Inconsistent date formats between browsers and database

Tags: php, date

One of my fields on my form is a date, whilst using google chrome it gives a calendar box when clicking on that field. If I select a date the format is DD-MM-YYYY but when it is added to my table it appears as YYYY-MM-DD.

Im guessing I'm missing something on my code and its setting it to the default format when inserting?
This is my insert code:

```
if (isset($_POST['addloan'])):

$username=$_POST['username'];

$user_query="SELECT * from loanusers where username = '$username'"; //think about how you are storing usernames in db, in this query you have to enter the username exactly how it is stored    
$userresult= mysqli_query($connection, $user_query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($userresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$emailaddress = $row['emailaddress'];

$product=$_POST['product'];
$product_desc=$_POST['product_desc'];
$serial=$_POST['serial'];
$date_collected=$_POST['date_collected'];
$date_return=$_POST['date_return'];
$returned=$_POST['returned'];

if (isset($_FILES['loanform'])){
    $exten = pathinfo($_FILES['loanform']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $loanform = $_FILES['loanform']['name'];
    $uploadfile = "loanforms/$loanform";

    if (strtolower($exten) == 'pdf'){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['loanform']['tmp_name'] , $uploadfile);
        $my_query="INSERT INTO loans VALUES ('','$username','$emailaddress','$product','$product_desc','$serial','$date_collected','$date_return','$loanform','$returned','')";
        $result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);
    } else{
        header('Location: incorrectext.php');
    }
}


    if ($result):
            header ('location: homepage.php?confirm=New loan successfully created');
        else :
            echo "<b>This didn`t work, error: </b>";
            echo mysqli_error($connection);
endif;
```

endif;

Comment: your code is very vulnerable to **SQL Injection** - just imagine someone posting the username `'; DROP TABLE loanusers; --`. please learn about parameterized queries to protect yourself, and don't forget rule #1: **never trust user input**. see also: [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: database always accept the date in the format of  YYYY-MM-DD it wont accept DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: It is not a php matter. It is a format of date in db.

Comment: try to convert the date format `date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date_return));`

Comment: so before inserting into database you need to convert the date (DD-MM-YYYY) format to (YYYY-MM-DD) using strtotime and then insert into the database.

Comment: @NishantNair it wont work since db will convert it back to its original format.

Comment: yes date will be stored in  mysql format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @malutki5200 ok in that case is there a reason why I dont get the calendar box in IE, does IE not support it?

Comment: @Mucca019 Yes, Only chrome supports it. You have to use plugins for other browsers.

Comment: there are different js file which you need to include for getting the box on ie

Answer (score 0):

Your database table is most probably set up to store dates in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. The best thing you can do is to reformat the date before and after the submission of your form.

```
// $date holds your submitted date in DD-MM-YYYY
$date = $_POST['date'];

// Reformat date
$oDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date);

// In your query
$stmt = 'insert into table (somevalue, someother, date) VALUES ('bla', 'blabla', '".$oDate->format('Y-m-d')."')';
```

The same thing can be done when retrieving the date:

```
<?php
$date = '2016-12-10';
$oDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
?>

<input type="date" value="<?= $oDate->format('d-m-Y'); ?>" />
```

#### Update

Browsers are unrestricted in how they present a date input. Chrome for example will use the user's local date format in their date picker. In your backend this can cause quite some problems.

That's why I would like to suggest changing your `date` to a `text` input and adding a datepicker using `jQuery`. This will prevent inconsistent dates from being submitted and gives you a greater control over the submitted format.

Comment: Though date input fields might show different formats, they all contain the same value in the end: `YYYY-MM-DD`.